# Convert from a list of datetime to a date in Python to filter a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, filter

I have the next date:

```
0   2019-06-29
Name: end date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

This is a part of the dataframe named data:

```
 data
    PointAlias       start Date    end date
 0   AO122732        2018-06-29    2019-06-29
```

then I transform it with the next code:

```
end_date_transformed = []
for x in range(len(data['end date'])):
    transf = pd.to_datetime(data['end date'][x]).date()
    end_date_transformed.append(transf)
end_date_transformed
output: [datetime.date(2019, 6, 29)]
```

I want to know if it is possible to transform it from a list to just a string to apply `datetime.datetime.strftime(end_date_transformed, %Y%m%d')`.
Is there a way of doing it?
The final objective of this is to be able to filter a dataframe of dates to just get those dates that are `<= end_date_transformed`. Something like:

```
df
     date
0   2018-06-29
1   2018-10-29
2   2019-02-28
3   2019-06-29
4   2019-10-29
5   2020-02-29

df[df['date'] <= end_date_transformed] # This does not work, the output is:
ValueError: Arrays were different lengths: 44 vs 1
```

I understand that the code above will not work, but if I do a datetime.date(year, month, day) and use it like `end_date_transformed` it works so the problem is in the transformation of the end date. 
If someone can help, I will be grateful.
Thank you so much for taking your time to read it and answer.

Comment: Why are you storing it as a list in the first place?

Comment: to make it readable to python. But I don't know if it is the correct way, because I am new with that @rahlf23

Comment: In other words, are you only going to have a single end date? Or do you intend to have multiple end dates?

Comment: @rahlf23 more than one date.

Comment: Ok, so where are the other end dates? Can you post your original dataframe? Your question is confusing, as it appears you have multiple dataframes floating around.

Comment: @rahlf23 the other end dates are out of range for this df, so if you know how to do it with just one end date would be perfect

Comment: Sure thing, can you then please include your full dataframe so we can see where `end date` is coming from (very first part of your question)?

Comment: @rahlf23 Done. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you for a single end date:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

data = pd.DataFrame([['A0122732','2018-06-29','2019-06-29']], columns=['PointAlias','start date','end date'])

df = pd.DataFrame([
['2018-06-29'],
['2018-10-29'],
['2019-02-28'],
['2019-06-29'],
['2019-10-29'],
['2020-02-29']],
columns=['date'])

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')

end_date = datetime.strptime(data['end date'].values[0], '%Y-%m-%d')

df[df['date'] <= end_date]
```

Returns:

```
        date
0 2018-06-29
1 2018-10-29
2 2019-02-28
3 2019-06-29
```

Comment: when I run  `end_date = datetime.strptime(data['end date'].values[0], '%Y-%m-%d')` I get this error :  `TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not numpy.datetime64`. the other parts work perfect

Comment: It appears that your `data['end date']` column is already of type `datetime`, so you don't need to perform the conversion. You should instead be able to directly call `df[df['date'] <= data['end_date'].values[0]]` and ignore the line defining `end_date` in my answer

Comment: That works perfect. Thank you so much for everything

Comment: You bet, glad I could help!